# mail configure work but not see any mails

Tags: php, email

I have confirgured setting email in php.ini and sendmail.ini. However i can not receive any email. Here my code

```
<?php
$to="someone@gmail.com";
//$to="someone2@yahoo.com";
$subj="test";
$mess="Sloth";
$header="testing";
$from="From: someone3@gmail.com";
if($mailsend=mail($to,$subj,$mess,$header,$from))
{
    echo 'sent';
}
else
{

echo 'error';
}
```

it output `sent` without any errors but i not receive any gmail.

Comment: have you checked your spam folder? Also, it sometimes take a (long) while to send the e-mail...

Comment: The main problem is your headers `$header="testing";` change that to a [**proper header**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), or remove it along with `$header,` and it will fire up. Also get rid of `$mailsend=` --- (*tested*)

Comment: I removed the $header but it still doesn't work and also use mail as you mentioned but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3228228 Did you consult [`my answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22692525/) ?

Answer (score 0):

When sending mail through the PHP System poorly configured mail settings can often be rejected for spam and not even reach its destination. Most often by the commercial email services such as google, hotmail & yahoo.

The solution here is to use a class that is configured almost perfectly of which will achieve the desired result by getting the mail to its destination.

I recommend http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

I use this for most of my mail applications, its easy to use, and it gets mails to the destination every time.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your headers `$header="testing";` change that to a [**proper header**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), or remove it along with `$header,` and it will fire up. Also get rid of `$mailsend=` there is no reference to it.

(*tested*) `mail()` was **not** sent *nor* received using your code; not in its present form.

*Plus*, at the very least it would have ended up in Spam, but this was not the case.

#### (Works)

```
<?php
$to="someone@yahoo.com";
$subj="test";
$mess="Sloth";
$from="From: someone2@gmail.com";
if(mail($to,$subj,$mess,$from))
{
    echo 'sent';
}
else
{

echo 'error';

}
```

---

Here is a basic header example:

#### (Works)

```
$to = 'you@example.com';
$mail_from = "email@example.com";
$subject = 'Message sent from website';
$message = "Message here";
$name = "Name here";
$header = "From: $name <$mail_from>";

   // Send it
   $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
   if($sent) {

    echo "Success";

   } else {
    echo 'Sorry, your message could not be sent.';
   }
```

---

For more information:

- [**Visit PHP.net**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on mail headers.